# Obtaining address of custom data-type in C from Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes, python-c-extension

I have a `vector` struct in C with the following fields,

```
struct vector {
    unsigned char* data;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long elemsize;
    unsigned long capacity;
};
```

and there are a few functions which correspondingly act on `vector` instances, such as:

```
struct vector* vector_new(unsigned long elemsize);
void vector_delete(struct vector* vec);
void vector_push_back(struct vector* vec, void* value, unsigned long elemsize);
void vector_reserve(struct vector* vec, unsigned long cap);
...
```

and so on (mimicking a c++ style `std::vector`).

In other sections of my code base I have component structs, for example `mirror`:

```
struct mirror {
    double R;
    double T;
    // extra fields omitted - see mirror_wrapper.py below
    struct vector* input[2]; // [vector<beam>*, vector<beam>*]
    struct vector* output[2]; // [vector<beam>*, vector<beam>*]
};
```

which, amongst others, has the following methods,

```
struct mirror* mirror_alloc();
int mirror_init(double R, double T, struct mirror* mrr);
// ibn is the "initial-beam-number"
void mirror_set_left_input(struct vector** input, unsigned long ibn, struct mirror* mrr);
void mirror_set_right_input(struct vector** input, unsigned long ibn, struct mirror* mrr);
```

where one passes the address of another components' `output` field to these `set_input` methods to "connect" them.

The `input` and `output` fields of every component *always* store instances of `struct beam` - a data-type which simply stores a `double complex` field and a `double` field.

---

Currently I am in the process of building wrappers in Python (3.5) to call the various methods in an object-oriented to use later on for easier plotting and so forth; using ctypes to build a shared library of the C code.

The following are the wrappers that I have so far,

**`vector_wrapper.py`**

```
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import Structure
from ctypes import c_ubyte
from ctypes import c_ulong
from ctypes import POINTER

class Vector(structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("data", POINTER(c_ubyte)),
        ("size", c_ulong),
        ("elemsize", c_ulong),
        ("capacity", c_ulong)]
```

**`mirror_wrapper.py`**

```
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import Structure
from ctypes import byref
from ctypes import c_double
from ctypes import c_ubyte
from ctypes import c_ulong
from ctypes import c_bool
from ctypes import POINTER
from ctypes import pointer
from vector_wrapper import Vector
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./ctn_lib.so')

class Mirror(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("R", c_double),
        ("T", c_double),
        ("pR", c_double),
        ("pT", c_double),
        ("tuning", c_double),
        ("mass", POINTER(c_double)),
        ("last_time", c_double),
        ("net_force", c_double),
        ("dfcoeff", c_double),
        ("phfcoeff", c_double*2), #phfcoeff is a double complex in c code
        ("rpfcoeff", c_double),
        ("input", POINTER(Vector)*2),
        ("output", POINTER(Vector)*2),
        ("has_left_input", c_bool),
        ("has_right_input", c_bool)]
```

Is there any way in which I can get the address of an `output` field of some component (say a `mirror`), which has the type `struct vector**`, and pass this to, e.g., some function `Mirror.set_left_input` as the `input` parameter?

Also, I assume it is necessary to create all fields in the `_fields_` of a python structure corresponding to the fields in the C structs - i.e. is it possible to omit some fields from this descriptor or not?

Comment: That `elemsize` indicates you want some generic storage. YOu should be aware you code very easily can invoke undefined behaviour. If you want to store different element, use `union`s.

Comment: In the case of the `input` and `output` fields of all components, such as `mirror`, the `elemsize` will always be the same - given by `sizeof(struct beam)` (where `beam` is defined elsewhere). I do use `vector` elsewhere to store other data-types, but `input` and `output` fields always store `beam`s.

Comment: I believe the answer is "yes", but without a clear example of the attempt and the problems encountered I don't know how to direct you from here.  You'd need a `class mirror(ctypes.Structure)` defined, at least, to access the `output` parameter of the `mirror` obj, and could then access the address by `ctypes.byref`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen If I make `Mirror` inherit from `ctypes.Structure` then I will need a `_fields_` descriptor in which I give the `output` field - however the type of this field is `struct vector*` in the C-code, what would this translate to in terms of ctypes default types? `POINTER(c_ubyte)`?

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury If you just need the pointer and not access to the vector itself (which won't really work with ctypes), `c_void_p` would probably be appropriate.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Oops, I forgot it wasn't a C++ vector.  Define a `class vector(ctypes.Structure)` as well, and use `POINTER(vector)` as the type in the `Mirror` definition.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've made some updates to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way in which I can get the address of an output field of some component (say a mirror), which has the type struct vector**, and pass this to, e.g., some function Mirror.set_left_input as the input parameter?

To access the output component of a Mirror given your structures:

```
>>> m = Mirror()
>>> m.output[0]
<__main__.LP_Vector object at 0x00000199607CA0C8>
```

To pass it to a function by reference:

```
>>> mirror_set_left_input(byref(m.output[0]),...)
```

> Also, I assume it is necessary to create all fields in the *fields* of a python structure corresponding to the fields in the C structs - i.e. is it possible to omit some fields from this descriptor or not?

No, you cannot omit fields from your structure definition, or the binary layout of the underlying C structure won't be correct.

Comment: Seems to work at the moment, more thorough testing to do but should be fine - cheers again!